# Broken file icons in "Open" dialogs

Tags: windows-7

Somewhere in the last few months the common Open File Dialog in my Windows 7 install started getting corrupt.  More specifically, the folders on the left-hand side and the main window folders & icons show the default "missing icon" visual.  Folders with a desktop.ini (like Project Docs under favorites) seem to show correctly.

I've deleted my thumbs.db and restarted explorer.exe, and I've run sfc.exe.  Neither did anything.

Any idea what's going on and how to fix Windows?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and this helped fix my problem:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/icons-in-save-as-and-open-dialog-windows-appear-as/d1a427e3-f1f0-4ada-994a-5d28a1f97389

It basically says to go to your command prompt and type
sfc /scannow

as administrator.